# how to turn on multi threading BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Im trying to use boots 1.67.0 in visual studio on windows to compile the boost thread example but im getting a error that i can not find the issue to. I think the error may be i am missing a #define but im not sure how i can work it out.   boost seams to be working fine in till i start using threading. when i downloaded boost i have not run bjam iv just used added the directory to my include and linker setting. Dose any one know how to resolve this ?

the error im getting in VS is:
c:\librarys\boost_1_67_0\boost\config\requires_threads.hpp(29): fatal error C1189: #error:  "Threading support unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"

**EDIT 2*
I have now built the library as it was pointed out to me that to use threads in boost i needed to so i opened bjam and ran the following command  "bjam -a --build-type=complete  threading=multi"  but i still get the error. do i need to use pre-compiled headers in my settings?

[image: c/c++ props]

Comment: You should not define `BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS`

Comment: i am not defining BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS in my program

Comment: Error message tells otherwise.

Comment: please see my code i have added. yes my error message is saying that but. i do not think this is define by me maybe by the library ?? I have used other code to test this if it something im am doing but it dose the same. the code i am using is a boost example the i have just coped and pasted.

Comment: You should locate the `BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS` definition then. Try jumping there from VS and check project settings. Also I think boost thread requires dynamic library to be compiled. Just adding boost dirs to linker setting is not enough, you need to actually build those libraries for linker to link anything.

Comment: yes you are correct. i have now built the libs. but still getting the same error. very frustrating. if i run find all in VS with "#define BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS i cant see any extra defines. would i be correct in saying in they should change colour (in my case white being not defined and purple being defined).I also edited my question to ask about my c/c++ prop settings. thanks.

Comment: The issues turned out to be i had disable language extensions in Visual studio.  Which in turn disabled disables threading in boost.